# Finding minimum and maximum values of an unknown continuous loop

Tags: c++, algorithm, while-loop

I am trying to find the minimum and maximum values for the continuous while loop given below, but somehow I am unable to get the logic right. Kindly let me know where I am going wrong.

```
while (true)
   {
         Function(&RawX, &RawY, &RawZ);// Keeps generating new RawX,Y and Z values

         if(MaxRawX < RawX)
            MaxRawX = RawX;
         if(MinRawX > RawX)
            MinRawX = RawX;

         Output("MaxRawX:%0.2f",MaxRawX);
   }
```

The problem that I am facing with the above algorithm is that the values of RawX, RawY and RawZ are continuously changing. For eg: at one point, I have values ranging from -46 to -35. I want my program to display MinRawX as -46 and MaxRawX as -35. At some other point, I might have values in between 201 to 215, where I want it to display MaxRawX as 215 and MinRawX as 201. Its basically some sensor angle data I receive from my hardware. I am sure I am doing something wrong here considering this being very basic but can't figure it out. Any suggestions?

Comment: IIUC, it appears that you may need to flush your `MaxRawX` and `MinRawX` values from time to time.

Comment: Is this multithread program? Can more than one thread write to the variables?

Comment: Not really, its just an endless while loop written in main(). The Raw values keep changing due to sensor movement.

Comment: I think the first thing you need to to is to work out more precisely what you want. Apparently your min and max values aren't meant to be the minimum and maximum over the whole of history; so what exactly *are* they? Once you know that, it'll probably be much more obvious what you need to do to get the results you want.

Comment: std::min might come handy for these kinds of things

Comment: *"at one point, I have values ranging from -46 to -35. I want my program to display MinRawX as -46 and MaxRawX as -35"* -- By this, do you mean during one single iteration of the loop, the variables `RawX`, `RawY` and `RawZ` range from -46 to -35?  Or do you mean that for the duration of a particular period in time, the variable `RawX` ranges from -46 to -35? Or something else entirely?

Comment: In one single iteration, I get one value i.e. may be say -40, at some different iteration I might get -35 or -45 or -43 or -36 etc. Basically the hardware that is transmitting me this data is fluctuating this value for some range which I am not aware of (but at one particular orientation it does not change much). So, just to figure out as to what is the max or min value during that particular hardware orientation.

Comment: @TheNewbie: Which is what my first comment was about :) You will need to figure out a way to know when the hardware orientation changes and reset your min/max values. It may so happen that you miss one or two values around the switch, but I guess you should be able to live with it.

Comment: Then you need to define what you consider a change in hardware orientation: is it when the raw value changes drastically (for instance going from 20 to 50 in one iteration)? Can the change be more gradual? What if the range simply grows (for instance, what if it goes from 20-30, to 25-35, then to 20-40, etc.)? You really need to think more thoroughly what your requirements exactly are, otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to have the minimum and maximum **for a given time frame**. The solution you use keep the minimum and maximum since the beginning of the program.

Depending on your needs, you have several solutions: for instance, you can simply reset the min and max from time to time, like @dirkgently suggested. If you want a moving range, so that at any point in time you have the min and max of the `n` last measurements, then you will have to use a more complex solution. The only one I can think of is keeping the measurements in a FIFO container:

```
std::deque<int> lastRawXs;
const int frameSize = 100; // only keep the last 100 measures    

while (true)
{
    // Keeps generating new RawX,Y and Z values
    Function(&RawX, &RawY, &RawZ);// 

    if (lastRawXs.size() >= frameSize)
    {
        lastRawXs.pop_front();
    }
    lastRawXs.push_back(RawX);

    typedef std::deque<int>::const_iterator iterator;
    std::pair<iterator, iterator> minMaxRawX =
        boost::minmax_element(lastRawXs.begin(), lastRawXs.end());

    Output("MinRawX:%0.2f", *minMaxRawX.first);
    Output("MaxRawX:%0.2f", *minMaxRawX.second);
}
```

**Edit**: Here is an alternative (better) solution using a [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer):

```
const int frameSize = 100;
std::circular_buffer<int> lastRawXs(frameSize);

while (true)
{
    Function(&RawX, &RawY, &RawZ); // keeps generating new RawX,Y and Z values

    lastRawXs.push_back(RawX); // overwrites old measures if buffer is full

    typedef std::circular_buffer<int>::const_iterator iterator;
    std::pair<iterator, iterator> minMaxRawX =
        boost::minmax_element(lastRawXs.begin(), lastRawXs.end());

    Output("MinRawX:%0.2f", *minMaxRawX.first);
    Output("MaxRawX:%0.2f", *minMaxRawX.second);
}
```

Comment: I wish I could give a +2 for the introduction of both a sliding window concept *and* the `boost::mix_max_element` function. I would certainly advise a `deque` here.

Comment: @MatthieuM. The best data structure would be a circular buffer, but there is no such container in the standard library (even though some implementations of `deque` use a circular buffer internally). Could you elaborate on why you would advise `deque` instead of `list`? As far as I can tell, the complexity of the operations used are similar for both: constant time insertion at the beginning and the end, linear time iteration. Perhaps the `deque` would incur less memory allocations, and provide better caching opportunities?

Comment: @MatthieuM. I just noticed that Boost provide a circular buffer implementation. Sometimes, I wondered if there is anything Boost does not provide :-)!

Comment: `deque` is all about memory usage. `list` will allocate one node per element. The node contains at least two pointers (to previous and next nodes). Therefore here we are talking about a node of one `int` and two `node*`, 24 bytes (assuming 64bits) per node for an element of 4 bytes. That's wasteful and trashes the cache :x Instead a `deque` will be much more compact. Of course, the circular buffer would be even better performance-wise; I don't remember if Boost's version conforms to the requirements in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your input guys. I was able to resolve the problem with all the answers provided!

Answer (score 2):

It seems you only want a *recent* max/min value, so you could do something like the following:

```
const int MAX_AGE = 1000; // number of samples before min/max expires
int MinRawXAge = INT_MAX;
int MaxRawXAge = INT_MAX;

while (true)
{
    if (MinRawXAge > MAX_AGE) // test to see whether MinRawX has expired
    {
        MinRawX = INT_MAX;
        MinRawXAge = 0;
    }

    if (MaxRawXAge > MAX_AGE) // test to see whether MaxRawX has expired
    {
        MaxRawX = INT_MIN;
        MaxRawXAge = 0;
    }

    Function(&RawX, &RawY, &RawZ); // Keeps generating new RawX, Y and Z values

    if (MaxRawX < RawX) // test for new MaxRawX
    {
        MaxRawX = RawX;
        MaxRawXAge = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        MaxRawAge++;
    }

    if (MinRawX > RawX) // test for new MinRawX
    {
        MinRawX = RawX;
        MinRawXAge = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        MinRawAge++;
    }

    Output("MinRawX: %0.2f, MaxRawX: %0.2f", MinRawX, MaxRawX);
}
```

This tracks the *age* (in samples) of the min and the max values, and when they exceed a predetermined threshold (1000 samples in the above case) they "expire" and get replaced by more recent min/max values.

Comment: Is there an increment missing somewhere in here?

Comment: Forgot to initialize INT_MAX and INT_MIN? :)

Comment: @The Newbie: `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` are defined in `<limits.h>`.

Comment: Thanks for your input guys. I was able to resolve the problem with all the answers provided!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you probably have problem with your specification.

Your code will continuously print current max values. But from your description it seems, that you actually don't want max values. So what do you want?

You need correct specification before you start writing code.

Comment: I need both Max and Min values from the Raw values. Basically, the raw values fluctuate between a range of values at a particular time. I am just trying to figure out a way to get the max and min value at that point.

Comment: @TheNewbie  Well, you are doing that, but you apparently don't want that. So sit down and write down what you need. It's obviously not minimum and maximum.